# Why don't countries welcome high energy prices to fight climate change?

Tags: climate-change, energy-policy

There're lots of people who believe climate change is happening and think governments should take action to curb emissions.

Given that, it seems natural to welcome high fossil fuel prices - in fact, the higher the better. That's because high prices should dampen demand, which leads to less carbon emissions.

However, I see news articles such as [this](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/the-high-price-of-biden-e2-80-99s-foolish-energy-policy-and-saudi-squabble/ar-AA12XHC9) and [this](https://www.lbc.co.uk/news/liz-truss-freeze-energy-prices-next-election-pm/) where countries are taking steps to cap/lower fossil fuel prices. This applies even when the government/political party say they consider climate change a major problem. Why?

The obvious explanation (and the one given by the US in one of the links above) is that they want to lower energy prices to lower Russian state revenue, which in turn makes Russia less able to prosecute the war in Ukraine. However, this explanation seems dubious because the US has tried to lower fossil fuel prices since before February 2022 ([example](https://www.csis.org/analysis/biden-has-few-options-lower-gasoline-prices)).

Another possible explanation is that high fossil fuel prices does not lead to less carbon emissions, but I can't see why that wouldn't be the case. Demand for energy might be inelastic to some extent, but only to some extent (c.f. how world energy usage dropped during Covid).

The only other explanation I can think of is very cynical: the electorate support curbing emissions as long as someone else is paying for it. If they have to pay for it (by higher energy bills) then they don't support it anymore. By extension, governments (at least those that are democratically elected) must try to lower fossil fuel prices even if it leads to more carbon emissions.

I'm looking for an explanation why climate-conscious governments (and climate change activists for that matter) aren't welcoming high energy prices with open arms.

Comment: 'Energy usage dropped during Covid' because of reduced _activity_ (<=> economy). Nobody wants that (except for, perhaps, fringe 'eco-fascists'). So it's not a good example. The link between economy size and energy consumption is indeed quite inelastic (even if not 100% rigid), and changes happen only long-term. (And yes, 'the electorate' doesn't buy 'suffer now for the brighter future' well).

Comment: @Zeus on a personal level there ought to be many things that can reduce energy usage though - e.g. drive less, use fans instead of air conditioning, take shorter showers, etc. Presumably all that will happen if energy prices are high.

Comment: Yes, but again, nobody wants that: it's explicit reduction of quality of life. People might _accept_ it, but most will not be happy about that.

Comment: @Zeus of course if people were truly rational, they’d easily trade a minor decrease in quality of life for a vast improvement of quality of life in the future and for their offspring. Unfortunately we’re not.

Comment: @Sebastiaan, rational conclusions depend on the premises, and they are, by definition, not entirely rational. What's a minor inconvenience for one is a dramatic compromise for another. Plus, the tolerance to uncertainty (of the future) is very different between individuals. We evolved ability to handle uncertainty and incomplete information, and it can't be deterministic. We are _different_, not just irrational, that's part of being human. But that's an entirely different discussion.

Comment: This change is too rapid for most countries (and people) to digest, even if we assume that their commitments to fighting global warming are made in good faith. Note also that household consumption is only a small part of the total - most of energy (including the fossil fuels) is consumed by industry and transportation. In this sense, suggestions like *driving less* and *heating less* are made mostly for public consumption (although contribution of such economies is non-negligible, it is not decisive.)

Comment: @Zeus that cuts to the point though doesn't it? If you use a carbon footprint calculator ([example](https://www.footprintcalculator.org/home/en)) then unless the Earth can already support 7 billion people who live like you (not likely for [Americans](https://iosfuzhu.com/how-many-global-acres-would-it-take-to-sustain-your-lifestyle) and probably most Western countries), then it's not possible to solve climate change without an explicit reduction in quality of life. In other words, if one is serious about fighting climate change, one ought to be ready to accept a reduction in QoL.

Comment: @Allure It's not that simple. Most people (and governments) fighting climate change don't want to keep the same carbon emissions per unit energy and cut carbon by drastically reducing energy consumption; they want to change energy *production* to produce drastically less carbon, and still keep using plenty of energy. So it's not clear that there is a fundamental requirement for quality of life to go down.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/why-do-governments-encourage-saving-resources-instead-of-simply-raising-the-pric

Comment: @zeus It look like you've posted an answer as a comment

Comment: How is that about Politics, rather than Economics or even Philosophy?

Comment: The world isn't ready to run completely on 100% green energy yet, it's a transition that will take considerable time, so it doesn't make much sense to hurt people financially to push them towards that. The practical alternative would be to reduce methane and deforestation caused by the livestock industry by [switching to a plant based diet](https://ourworld.unu.edu/en/eating-less-meat-essential-to-curb-climate-change-says-report). Taking away the subsidies given to the meat industry and using them to fund vegetable farmers and plant trees in the regained land, would be one way to do it.

Comment: Competitive disadvantage. A country which curbs CO2 emission hurts its economy in comparison to a country which does not curb. And the bill for the emission (climate change) is paid by both. Also, do you know that the whole western hemisphere emits about as many CO2 as rebel provinces of China (PRC)? Thus without their cooperation you can even shut the whole western economy down to zero its emission and still do not manage to halve the global emission.

Comment: Maybe we should welcome high food prices to combat obesity.

Comment: The question seems to lack any mention at all of poor people who simply can't afford price increases.

Comment: @GlenYates maybe not all food prices, but I can certainly see higher meat prices.

Comment: @Allure "higher meat prices", really!? If you really want to combat obesity, you would put higher prices on high carbohydrate, highly processed, and sugar added foods as well as soft drinks and diet soft drinks, and lower prices on natural high fat and high protein foods.

Comment: @GlenYates Higher meat prices wouldn't only be about obesity, but rather also about emissions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Countries don't want to stop climate change, because their electorates are over-leveraged.

You say:

> the electorate support curbing emissions as long as someone else is paying for it.

but even this is too generous. Actually, only a minority support stopping climate change. Allow me to introduce "NPC theory": The majority of the electorate consists of people who don't really care to think about such things as climate change, and just want to be able to follow their established routines. Anything which threatens the routine is a threat.

Why? Because a developed-country lifestyle is a house of cards, which is expensive and difficult to maintain. Anyone who's found a way to keep one would like to keep it. A misstep can result in the entire thing crashing down. Maintaining the status quo is much easier than finding an alternative route to keeping a similar lifestyle.

Consider a suburbanite who commutes by car to the city center for work. What happens if the gasoline price spikes 10x? Then on Saturday they can't buy gasoline according to the routine (unless they do it by credit card). On Monday they can't go to work. On Tuesday they don't have a job. Next week they can't pay rent. Next month the police show up to kick them out of their landlord's house. Next month after that, they are found dead under a bridge. Or, they can push it back by a month or two by buying gasoline on their credit card.

In the long run they should either live in the city center near their work, or commute by good public transit. Either of those would also be an acceptable lifestyle routine. But because there aren't enough apartments in the city center, and the best available public transit route includes a 45-minute stopover each way, and you already agreed to mortgage payments that *you calculated* based on being able to drive each day, you can't get from here to there without going through the intermediate state of dying under a bridge.

This is similar to the financial concept of leverage. The more leveraged a person's financial position is, the more they have to gain from favourable price changes, but the smaller of an unfavourable price change would make them bankrupt. Westerners' lifestyles, just like organizations in the western financial system, tend to be very leveraged and therefore completely intolerant of disruption. A few weeks ago, the UK's entire pension fund system nearly went bankrupt due to the snowball effect of an interest rate increase of only a few percent.

The mechanism by which high prices result in change is by trying to kill everyone (and bankrupt every business) that hasn't already made the change. Since the majority of people have not made the change, and don't want to (change is haaaaard!) they are strongly opposed to high prices.

People with more under-leveraged, flexible lifestyles - such as single young professionals - tend to be much more supportive of anything which changes the system, as they can accommodate the change, but this group is a relative minority.

Comment: this sentence is driving me mad: "Since the majority of people have not made the change, and don't want to (change is haaaaard!) they are strongly opposed to high prices."  why you say people don't want to? Maybe they can't afford it, both money-wise and time-wise? For example I thought about solar panels, but first I wasn't sure how long I would stay at my current house, secondly I couldn't afford it. Now I am not sure if I can invest in that as the price of everything goes up.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki if you cannot afford solar panels, you shouldn't rent a house, but a small apartment. That is less costly and even more green than a house you need to heat and maintain.

Comment: @verybigcat that's oversimplification isn't it. I don't want to go into details about my housing decisions. But my point is that many people feel that they can't afford the investment, not that they don't want. Also before the prices went up that definitely felt like a low priority or nice-to-have but not essential. But now when it maybe makes more economic sense, there is more uncertainty lingering. And with possibility of mortgage rates going up it is not straightforward to justify. Also why I couldn't afford it  was that I bought a new more efficient boiler initially

Comment: The problem about throwing around the "NPC" accusation, is it might suddenly turn around on you.  Unlike those NPCs, you're a good, smart person because you listen to the climate change alarmists, and don't think very hard about how some of the people raising the alarm are the same people who predicted famines in the 80s, and that New York would be underwater by 2012.  Solving real problems (and separating truth from overblown rhetoric) is hard, and if you think you see clearly, and the people who don't do what you want are all fools, you might be a fool, too.

Comment: @Jedediah if you actually read the answer, you might notice that I used "NPC" in the context of following a set routine, and not in reference to a political ideology. You are doing the political-NPC thing by implying that every usage of the word "NPC" is the political-NPC thing, which is a layer of meta-irony I didn't realize was possible.

Comment: @user253751 I don't see how your remark addresses my criticism.  You seem to be suggesting people that are more concerned with their own needs than with climate change rhetoric are NPCs, who don't understand / can't be bothered with the bigger picture.  But some of them may disagree with the relative urgency of different things, judging from the complex and sometimes inconsistent messages they and you have received about climate change, and how they interpreted those messages.  I just meant your usage of NPC, not the general meme.  There is no meta-irony.

Comment: @user253751 "The majority of the electorate consists of people who don't really care to think about such things as climate change, and just want to be able to follow their established routines."  I think that's what you mean by NPC.  Because you said it.

Comment: Accepting one or another general narrative about climate change (because following the established routine), is also easy, whether or not it is justified.  Especially when it is other people who you're making the cost-benefit decisions for, without knowing the specifics of their lives.  Etc.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki the mere fact that most people consider low fuel prices as a reasonable excuse to be over-leveraged and have a high consumption, makes me dislike the average person.

Comment: @verybigcat history shows that it doesn't matter whether they are reasonable, it doesn't matter whether they are doing the right or wrong thing - you cannot make people do the right thing because they will gang up and shoot you (either literally or metaphorically). Gas prices are objectively too low? Tough, they stay like that or you will be forced to go away. Then the gas runs out, the summer is 70 degrees (Celsius) and everyone is huddling around the AC in their bunkers wondering why nobody did anything to stop it.

Comment: @user253751 people evolved by hunting meat. We were first animals that could effectively wipe out mammoths, and we did. After 2 million years of learning to hunt smaller and smaller game animals, we were forced to learn agriculture. That happen 10000 years ago, and since mastering agriculture we've only multiplied in numbers and increased our living standard. That's apparently not enough, we have to overspend on fuel and have massive debt while running at capacity already. So yeah, you may be right, we may overextend on carbon footprint until it gets hot.

Comment: @verybigcat or some frustrated citizens do some actual damage the energy infrastructure, extinctioning all the cossil fuel users

Comment: @user253751 is it a real possibility? Imagine the amount of wealth and power needed to sabotage energy infrastructure with military means. Doesn't seem like a small fringe groups could pull it off. Also... People interested in taking down power state-owned power plants may be strongly conflicted. Somehow I don't see how anti-state anarcho-capitalists would be so frustrated with climate change, that can fight the police together with leftists and eco-fascists. Doesn't seem like it would actually happen. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @verybigcat You might be surprised (a) how little damage it takes to make a temporary impact, (b) how few temporary impacts add up to a big impact, and (c) how poorly defended some infrastructure is outside of war. Or just look at Ukraine. Despite being a whole country with half the West behind them, they still can't stop missiles hitting their substations. And this is a country that's at war and knows it has to defend its subtations. Alternatively look at how far right groups broke some substations in the USA a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 36):

#### On the long run, maybe. But not on the short run.

If gasoline prices are higher for a long time, people buy smaller and more efficient cars. Something like that could be seen if one compares the European and US car market since the [1970s oil shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_oil_crisis), but then came the [SUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport_utility_vehicle#2010s_to_2020s) (which, admittedly, defies this explanation).

If the price rises quickly, people can't just junk their old cars and buy a new one. Not financially, and it would be bad for the environment as well if everybody purchased *new* smaller cars. So either they pay the higher prices and grumble, or they drive less -- but few people drive for fun. Trips are to the workplace, for shopping, to bring children to school.

Same with gas or oil for heating. On the long run, people buy ground source heat pumps, they insulate their windows, etc. On the short run, they pay more or shiver. And there are two more problems with this. For one, the amortization on heating systems is at least as long as for cars. For another, often the decision what to install belongs to a landlord while tenants pay the bill. (On the long term, more-expensive-to-heat apartments should have lower rents, but the housing market is stressed in much of the world).

Finally, by conflating climate and the energy price spike, one would make it look as if one could trade one sector for the other. If one needs to reduce my carbon footprint by a certain amount, one might be able to make the choice between housing, transportation, and diet composition. So if one *really* wants to eat plenty of red meat, one would have to give in to Russia. But accepting Russian aggression that way is a dangerous precedent.

Answer (score 20):

Existing answers are very good, but a couple of further thoughts:

On the political side:  Climate change kills.  But for now, it largely kills people in the developing world, whose grieving relatives don't get a vote in the elections of developed countries.  Hypothermia associated with unaffordable energy prices this winter will kill rather fewer people, but many of them will be people whose grieving relatives *do* get a vote in the elections of developed countries.

On the technical side: Yes, high gas prices incentivize people and businesses to invest in improved energy efficiency and in decarbonized energy generating capacity, and that's good.  Unfortunately, they also incentivize people and businesses to switch from burning natural gas to coal, which is even more dangerous to the climate system; and they incentivize oil and gas companies to invest more in exploration for new oil and gas resources, and in technology for more complete extraction of already-known resources (e.g. fracking), which may actually lead to more oil and gas being extracted and burnt in the long run.

Comment: COVID deaths didn't cause grieving relatives to vote in favour of policies to reduce COVID. Why should this be different with energy?

Comment: @user253751 I wasn't thinking so much of voting for or against specific policies, as of people who are generally unhappy due to bereavement being more inclined to vote against incumbents.

Comment: @user253751 Is that truly the case? Leaving aside the question of what proportion of the electorate consisted of such relatives. Are you sure that their idea of policies which reduce Covid isn't (rightly or wrongly) different from yours? "On issue X, people voted for policies which I consider foolish" isn't quite the same as "People don't care about X". I propose that in whatever country you are referring to, there might be less diagreement about the policies responsible for deaths due to lack of heating then there was Covid deaths.

Comment: COVID has killed 0.32% of the US population.  Grieving relatives just aren't a big enough constituency to swing an election.

Comment: And also a lot of COVID deaths did have some comorbidity, so they were partly counted as nature taking it's course. Most people have COVID and not die, therefore lots of people just don't care too strongly.

Comment: @dan04 median age of a Covid death was 80 in the US. It wasn’t seen as a tragedy in most cases, just a natural death that was slightly accelerated by a virus.

Answer (score 14):

### Because there are no viable alternatives on the market to existing sources of energy

Environmentalists don't necessarily want expensive energy, they just want to price the existing cheap solutions (coal, oil, natural gas, etc) out of the market so they can replace them with  renewable solutions like solar and wind. The catch is you can't just yank existing options off the market. California, one of the places trying to do the most in this area, [had to keep its Diablo Canyon nuclear reactor running](https://calmatters.org/environment/2022/09/diablo-canyon-legislature-california/) because it represents a not-insignificant source of non-carbon electricity

> The plant, which provides about 10% of the state’s electricity, is a clean source of energy that supporters say is needed to help the state meet its carbon neutral goals. Carbon neutrality means achieving a balance between the carbon added to the atmosphere and the carbon removed.

And this from [a state that has half its power from non-carbon sources](https://www.energy.ca.gov/data-reports/energy-almanac/california-electricity-data/2021-total-system-electric-generation)

> California's non-CO2 emitting electric generation categories (nuclear, large hydroelectric, and renewables) accounted for 49 percent of its in-state generation, compared to 51 percent in 2020. The change is attributable to the continued impacts from California’s ongoing drought.

The US [isn't building much in the way of nuclear power](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/38414/12027), and [renewable energy sources in the US are not up to the task](https://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.php?id=92&t=4)

> In 2021, renewable energy sources accounted for about 12.2% of total U.S. energy consumption and about 20.1% of electricity generation.

And as for consumer uses, [electric cars in the US only account for 1% of the market](https://www.caranddriver.com/news/a39998609/electric-car-sales-usa/)

> Currently, it's estimated that around 1 percent of the 250 million cars, SUVs, and light-duty trucks on American roads are electric.

[Some smaller European countries are getting better results in the consumer car market](https://insideevs.com/news/578743/norway-electric-car-sales-march2022/), but that doesn't even touch the largest emaining problem: diesel to power trucks that deliver goods to markets. Tesla (which is the only company apparently actively building electric semi trucks) [might get the first electric semi trucks on the road by Dec 2022](https://electrek.co/2022/10/06/tesla-semi-production-starts-pepsi-first-electric-trucks/) (assuming delivery dates don't slip again).

> In today’s tweet, Musk announced that Pepsico would get the first Tesla Semi deliveries on December 1. After the launch of Tesla Semi in 2017, PepsiCo placed one of the biggest orders for Tesla Semi: 100 electric trucks to add to its fleet. The company planned to use 15 of those trucks for a project to turn its Frito-Lay Modesto, California, site into a zero-emission facility. Last year, PepsiCo said that it expected to take deliveries of those 15 Tesla Semi trucks by the end of the year before it was delayed again.

Elon Musk [claims the semis will get 500 miles per charge](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1578171356482371585). [Consumer electric pickup trucks have not fared well in towing, however](https://www.businessinsider.com/ford-f150-lightning-towing-electric-truck-downside-youtube-video-2022-10)

> Car and Driver hitched a 6,100-pound camper to each of the three electric pickups on the market: the F-150 Lightning, GMC Hummer EV, and Rivian R1T. At 70 mph in 85-degree conditions, maximum range dropped to 100 miles for the Ford, 140 miles for the Hummer, and 110 miles for the Rivian.

Remember that semi trucks make most of the deliveries around the world. The price of fuel directly impacts consumers, regardless of whether or not you drive an EV.

### TL;DR

1. Most places still use non-renewable energy for a significant source of their electrical generation
2. Most of the consumer vehicle market is still using gas or diesel
3. There are no in-use electric semi trucks. Even if Tesla meets their Dec 1, 2022 delivery, that still means the vast majority of all semis will be using diesel for the foreseeable future

Comment: The question asks about reducing usage, though.

Comment: @Allure Where? You mention it as a goal, but the title and the meat of your question is why they don't see higher prices as a path to achieve said goal.

Comment: The idea in the question is, the ultimate goal is to reduce emissions, and one way to do that is to reduce usage. Higher prices should reduce usage. This train of logic seems to hold regardless of what the source of the energy is.

Comment: And my answer is "Some emission sources cannot currently be replaced, which means you cannot just stop using those sources. When the price of fuel rises, it causes other things to rise as well". That was [the gripe with Pete Buttigieg saying the solution to higher gas prices was electric cars](https://nypost.com/2021/11/29/buttigieg-slammed-for-urging-electric-car-buying-to-counter-gas-prices/). Not only are those cars considerably more expensive, Buttigieg still has to buy groceries like everyone else, which are delivered by diesel truck.

Comment: @Machavity then they shall convert to electric trucks! or freight trains

Comment: @user253751 And as I explained in the answer, electric trucks are not yet a thing. Even if they were, you have to build infrastructure to support them (and electric trains). Most freight trains are also diesel powered

Comment: Additionally, you still have to provide power to charge electric vehicles.  How is that going to be generated?  This is going to be a significant problem for California in particular, at least in the short-medium term, given that it is actively trying to eliminate all usage of fossil-fuel vehicles within its borders, but it already doesn't have enough electricity to go around.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the grid in California only lacks energy in the evening. It has a surplus around noon. The solution is to charge the cars when the sun shines.

Comment: Because load shifting is working so very well now, @verybigcat? "Sometimes enough" is not the same as "enough".  California is barely scraping by now.  It doesn't want to build new fossil fuel or nuclear power plants, and it would prefer to shut down the ones it already has, yet it has a plan on the books that will drastically, unavoidably increase demand for electricity.  Other states are in somewhat better shape supply-wise, but few, if any, could support a major shift to electric vehicles with current or near-future capacity.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for my electric car load shifting works perfectly. I always charge it in the night because it's cheaper. If I lived in California, I would charge from morning to early afternoon. That's the good thing about having batteries - I skip high-demand hours to charge when it's cheaper.

Comment: @Machavity *Some emission sources cannot currently be replaced, which means you cannot just stop using those sources* Right but that doesn't stop one from using less energy, no? If one uses less energy then it doesn't matter where the energy is sourced from because emissions will drop.

Answer (score 9):

Because high energy prices don't fight climate change directly. All the higher prices do is hurt the economy as it makes everything more expensive to buy. It is the same reason they can't just shift over to green energy as the impact would be very bad for the economy.

What is needed to fight climate change is to reduce the costs and increase output of green energy so that it can replace existing sources.

This question shows why higher energy prices are not a way to fight climate change. Germany (and other countries) are trying to find ways to help their citizens pay for the energy they use after the sharp increases in prices. Those higher prices only reduce the use of that energy so far. It also increases the profits of the companies involved allowing them to spend more money on the same fuels.

[Why is Germany subsidizing the cost of electricity for everyone rather than only the poorest households?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75849/why-is-germany-subsidizing-the-cost-of-electricity-for-everyone-rather-than-only)

As long as those fuels are profitable they will still continue to be used.

EDIT:

As a note I have seen Germany and the energy prices pop up on my social media feed as well as various chat programs as a reason why going green is bad. Claims that green energy can't keep up and if they had focused more on coal/nuclear they would not have this problem. I have also seen claims that because Greta Thunberg saying nuclear power is better then coal is her endorsing nuclear power for the future

Comment: This makes absolute claims which are true short term but wrong long term. Higher fossil fuel prices don't make *everything* more expensive, only the things that make use of fossil fuel and fossil fuel based energy. Things that use little or no fossil fuel or energy become relatively cheaper. This makes these things more attractive ecomonically. This is exactly the mechanics how modern liberal economies try to fight climate change. But it only works slowly in the long term and it requires changes to behavior which are often unpopular.

Comment: Two things (1) They don't push up the price of fossil fuel energy, they push up the price of all energy because of how energy is sold and supply and demand. (2) It's not just a matter of economic output but people freezing to death.

Comment: @quarague As the other answer more clearly points out people dying in the short term is really bad and that is what this can lead to if when people experience extreme temperatures.

Comment: @quarague:  Electricity is not sold based on who makes it or the kind of electricity.  It's not like produce where I can see Apples vs. Oranges or Organic vs. Non-Organically raised.  I live in an area that in addition to fossil fuel electric plants also has Hydro-electric and nuclear power generation in the grid.  How do I know buy electricity that is only green?  Even then, there's a reason why I drive a gas powered car and not electric:  I couldn't afford the electric one when I bought it even if there are rebate incentives to buying electric cars.

Comment: @hszmv We may yet see the decoupling! If everyone who had a green energy contract before the energy crisis pays the green energy price and everyone else pays the fossil fuel energy price....

Comment: Obviously, if you "hurt the economy as it makes everything more expensive to buy" you help the climate, *ceteris paribus.* High energy prices **do** fight climate change, directly and immediately.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Hurting the economy and the people that are part if it in the name of fighting climate change doesn't do anything to help get support for climate change. One of the most common arguments I hear is how much more everything is going to cost if we ditch fossil fuel and it will make most things unaffordable.  It can actually harm the climate change movement if actions are taken that turn people away from making change because it convinces them that it will cause harm to them.

Comment: What you describe is clearly an *indirect* effect. As I said: High prices **do** curb emissions, immediately and directly, because material consumption is reduced. Of course nobody wants that but it was clearly visible during the oil price shocks of the 1970s and after the collapse of East Germany's economy in the 1990s.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica And they are used as tools against climate change as well. The high prices we are seeing are temporary and but they will be used for a longer time as arguments about why we need to keep using fossil fuels to fight high prices.  Letting high prices be the tool for fighting climate change lets people use those prices as a reason to not change.

Comment: @JoeW renewable energy is currently cheaper than fossil fuels, and that's somehow an argument in favour of fossil fuels?

Comment: @user253751 That depends on the area of the world you are in, and you are missing the point that higher prices is used to scare people away from renewable energy.

Comment: "Because high energy prices don't fight climate change directly." They do fight climate change. I don't see any value the word "directly" adds. "What is needed to fight climate change is to reduce the costs and increase output of green energy so that it can replace existing sources." What matters is not the absolute cost of green energy, what matters is whether it's cheaper than dirty energy. If the cost of dirty energy goes up, that makes green energy more attractive.

Comment: @Acccumulation And it also makes things more expensive for everyone in areas that do not have access to cheaper green energy and assumes that other energy sources don't also raise prices to take advantage of higher prices. Not to mention as I said several times already people will use the higher prices to attack green energy.

Comment: Don't higher prices hurt some people in the economy and help other people in the economy? It's not like the money just disapparates.

Comment: @user253751 How does higher prices help anyone but a select few? In general the reason people are charging higher prices is because they are also paying higher prices and need to charge more to make up for it. The only people who benefit from higher prices are people who don't have higher costs and that only helps if they don't end up selling less and making less overall.

Comment: @JoeW If prices are higher, either that additional money is going around in a circle, or someone at the end is getting more.

Comment: @user253751 while that is correct that doesn't change the fact that it only helps a limited number of people who don't also have increased costs. It is going to hurt a lot more people then it will help.

Comment: @user253751 If those people at the end are the Saudis, that doesn't help Americans.

Comment: "and assumes that other energy sources don't also raise prices to take advantage of higher prices" The only way that it would allow them to raise their prices is if the prices of other energy goes above the price of green energy. So it's rather bizarre that you think this is a counter to the argument that higher dirty energy costs would make green energy more competitive. And it's not like green energy is a monopoly that can raise its prices at will.

Comment: @Acccumulation Sure they are not a monopoly but it isn't as if they can't raise prices to match the rest of the market as prices changes. The massive price spikes you saw in Texas when they had a extreme cold wave should be evidence of everyone raising prices.

Comment: " it isn't as if they can't raise prices to match the rest of the market as prices changes. " Yes, it is. "The massive price spikes you saw in Texas when they had a extreme cold wave should be evidence of everyone raising prices." Because of decreasing supply. And that wasn't energy in general, it was electricity. The spot market of electricity is much different from the market for oil.

Answer (score 8):

Assume that your family has an income of $1000/month with:
Gas: $200
Fuel: $200
Food: $100

And after your idea, you will spend:
Gas: $400
Fuel: $400
Food: $200

Would you accept this price? In the past, every month you would save 500$, but now you would run out of money.

Comment: No, after the OP's idea, the family would decide that they can't afford their previous lifestyle, thus have to cut back on car trips and turn the heat down, such that the spending would end up looking like "Gas: $300; Fuel: $300; Food: $200". Sure, they won't be happy with this, but at least in this example they can actually afford it and it does reduce emissions.

Comment: Cutting back on your lifestyle is an option if there is actually things you can cut back on! For some "cutting back" means "Well, I guess I will not have food today" or "I guess I will have to either go into debt or see the wall rot from mold because I cannot heat the room"..

Answer (score 7):

I think your cynical view is essentially correct but I wouldn't see it as negatively as you do.

Goverments do use higher prices on fossil fuels through taxes combined with subsidies on greener forms of energy to encourage people to reduce their carbon dioxide emission. Most european countries have high taxes on petrol and at the same time give generous subsidies to electric cars. So they are explicitly using high fossil fuel prices to fight climate change. But these are long term projects and the question of how high the prices should be is controlled by the governments (and discussed intensively with vastly differing opinions). The goal here is a gradual move to a more climate friendly ecomony without any significant reductions in wealth or quality of live.

What happened now was a significant increase in raw (meaning before taxes) energy prices. So in the short term the only way people can react to these prices increases is by consuming less. They can't just switch to an electric car because petrol become more expensive or switch to non-fossil heating because gas is much more expensive this year compared to last year. They can only drive less and heat less which is unpopular. It also means that instead of everybody driving and heating as much as before but using more environmentally friendly ways to do it, the poor need to drastically restrict themselves whereas the more wealthy can continue as before, which is also politically unpopular.

So governments try to reduce the (hopefully) short term impact of very high prices somewhat while at the same time trying to encourage long term reductions in fossil fuel use.

Comment: There's been a lot of resistance to higher taxes on carbon, for instance [in France](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2018/dec/04/macron-u-turn-on-eco-tax-rise-gives-green-lobby-fuel-for-thought) - just because something's good for the environment doesn't mean it's easy or painless.

Comment: @StuartF I fully agree. Which also explains why if the governments control the process themselves they can try to do it relatively painless but if the prices hikes are externaly they try to cushion them to reduce the amount of economic pain.

Comment: I had to scroll down way too far for someone properly acknowledging the poor.

Answer (score 7):

For electricity, fossil fuel price surges cause consumers to be priced out of potentially life-critical energy by the **merit order/economic dispatch market** utilized in most countries.

Economic dispatch works by asking every provider to commit to the lowest price they're willing to sell their electricity for (usually in a short time interval, like the next 5 minutes), sorting the offers lowest-to-highest, and accepting the offers in that order until demand is met. The catch though is that *lower-cost offers get to benefit from the price set by the highest-cost accepted offer.*<sup>[1](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/eme801/node/532)</sup>

This means that if a solar plant and a coal plant both offer their energy at a 1% margin, but the coal plant's costs are twice as high as the solar plant's due to surging fuel prices, the solar plant collects an absurdly large ~100% margin. The theory is that this incentivizes producing lower-cost energy, and gives renewables companies capital they can re-invest.

The problem is that the savings of the lower-cost energy don't reach the consumer until that lower-cost energy represents 100% of the demand. As long as a single kilowatt is supplied by fossil fuels, consumers still pay fossil fuel prices and renewable producers pocket a massive windfall when fuel prices soar. (You may notice that this incentivizes renewables companies to *not* fill 100% of demand.)

This is a problem because people often die when they can't afford energy to heat their homes in the winter or cool their homes in the summer. This isn't good for the government's interests.

Comment: Through the magic of the free market, wouldn't such collusion incentivize someone else to come and fill the last 1% with renewables?

Comment: @user253751 you're assuming a free market. Access to the grid is not open to anyone though, it's tightly controlled by operators who are (situation in europe) under government control. Same for permissions to build powerplants.

Answer (score 5):

The abstract answer is: *Any* shock is bad for the economy.<sup>1</sup> Economies work best if developments are predictable so that resource use can be planned. Any change causes "friction": Adaptation is costly. The cost of change grows fast with its speed.

An energy price shock is exactly this kind of sudden, unpredicted, costly change: Previous investments become obsolete, resources must be diverted to new energy sources, the price spike lets companies go bankrupt (i.e., the resources invested in them are lost), unemployment rises, consumption drops, more ripple effects wreck havoc on the normally nicely balanced interplay of economic forces.

The transition to clean energy is urgent, but governments in democratic countries depend on their electorate. Creating economic insecurity and hardship is a fool-proof way for a government to lose the next election, so they cannot do that except as a heroic gesture which will be reverted by their successors.

Consider that one of the most straight-forward and most sustainable ways to reduce emissions is to simply shrink the economy<sup>2</sup>, but of course no sane government would do that on purpose.

That's why governments fight *quick rises* in energy prices, even those governments that in principle aim at higher prices for the future, as probably all Green parties do. They dampen price spikes in order to dampen the economic and social disruptions caused by them.

---

<sup>1</sup> As an example we can look at the shrinking of the Russian armed forces after the end of the Cold War, ending vast unproductive resource use and freeing hundreds of thousands of men in their productive prime. In principle, this should result in an economic boost. In reality though, hundreds of thousands of veterans returning home were actually a *burden.* Even this change which should exclusively cause economical benefits *hurt* the economy because of the disruptive nature of change itself.

<sup>2</sup> The main reason why Germany doesn't lag behind its climate goals even more than it already does is the collapse (or, if you want, the accounting for an already ongoing collapse) of the East German economy after the reunification.

Answer (score 4):

There are very good answers in this post, but a side note, on the perspective of the electorate (i.e. just the people in the streets).

This question assumes that the common people who complain about fossil fuels want a solution driven by the free market economy, as that is the premise of the question (higher prices->less use).

However, firstly this is not real, as many services of the world require energy. Trains, healthcare etc. Increasing the price may impact these heavily with no lowering of supply.

But mostly, many of the people complaining about fossil fuels do not necessarily want a "free market" solution. They want the government to own energy generation and distribution as a *service*, and to governments to take responsibility for the sources of this energy.
If it was like that, the increase of energy prices may have an increased support on the electorate. But currently, increased energy prices for fossil fuel companies would translate mostly to them getting the same profits by providing less services, which obviously people do not agree with. Common people worried about climate change don't tend to like to subsidize the companies that caused it in order to keep their profits up.

Comment: *the government to own energy generation and distribution as a service, and to governments to take responsibility for the sources of this energy* Can you describe how this works?

Comment: @Allure the literal same way than public transport, education or healthcare in most EU countries. There is nothing inherently complicated of making a service public. You simply shift the *purpose* of its function. In a free market economy, the purpose is, ultimately, make money. This is why in Europe you have the public services I mentioned.  Their purpose, by being government owned, is not making money, even if in some cases they can make money (e.g. public transport is some places), but instead to provide a service.

Comment: This can be applied to energy too, and in fact, in many countries, this was the original shape of the energy business, and it was later historically privatized.  Obviously, having this as a public or private service is on its own a political debate. My point was that indeed it is a political debate and there are some people (and many more activists) that argue that this is what they want. Not everyone wants free market capitalism as a solution, as some argue that it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: For transparency: I am a supporter of such policies that would aim to make public the energy sector. But the point of my answer was not to promote such ideas, just give you a view that many people have on this: free market capitalism is not the solution, and thus, the questions assumption is not entirely valid, as there are ways to tackle the problem that do not rely on the axioms of such economical system. This is why they don't support the price increase for fossil fuel removal.

Comment: That's how it works in many places isn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalization_of_oil_supplies "According to consulting firm PFC Energy, only 7% of the world's estimated oil and gas reserves are in countries that allow private international companies free rein. Fully 65% are in the hands of state-owned companies such as Saudi Aramco, with the rest in countries such as Russia and Venezuela"

Comment: @Allure while adjacent to the issue, you are showing a different thing. Those National oil companies are national in order to bring profit to the countries that have the oil. They are a *de facto* for profit organizations, such has been the geopolitcal importance of oil in the XX century. Clean energy could not  become like that, because its not a resource that can be sold in barrels.  (side note 7% is about *foreign*, not *private*, and 65% is about oil reserves, not  % of countries that allow this. E.g. Saudi Arabia is 16% alone, so is Venezuela, covering half of that 65%).

Comment: @Allure finally, re oil: oil accounts for a bit less than the total fossil fuel burning for energy, coal and gas being almost on the same level each. Its not a "just oil" situation, albeit I acknowledge you may have just shown that as an example. Regarthless, this is starting to become a political discussion on *how* to solve the issue, or ideas on such. That is not what the question was about, nor am I able to provide a thorough answer on that. Simply: some people believe this may be a better option. Regardless if it is, or it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

## Frame Challenge: Increased prices don't dampen demand, they *shift* who can *afford* the supply to a smaller subset of the demand.

One issue that might be worth noting is the presumption you're basing the idea of welcoming increased prices on:

> That's because high prices should dampen demand, which leads to less
> carbon emissions.

This, as I understands, presumes a few considerations:

1. People's demand for energy is flexible, and driven by the cost of energy.
2. If energy costs go up, people's demand for that same amount of energy they used to demand would adjust.
3. The cost of energy will have to eventually adjust to a build of energy not being actively utilized, preventing it from going higher without any reduction soon in response.

These may not be correct:

1. Most energy consumption is for aspects of life people need to keep going - gasoline cars to drive them to an area of work, to get groceries (Or to get groceries delivered to the store from the farms that create the goods, or the manufacturing plants, etc.), natural gas for heating during colder months -, and cutting demand for that energy leads to a lot of degradation of life. If you don't go to work, you can't make as much (If any) money to spend on anything else, if your store doesn't have groceries to buy, you run out of food, and if heating a cold place isn't done, you run the risk of frozen pipes of water pressure, cracking housing structures, or freezing to death, in certain climates. There can be an irreducible amount of demand someone has for energy, regardless of the cost.
2. Just because someone is priced out of the market doesn't mean that they still won't actually need what the market provides; they just can't afford it. You might consider this the same vein of housing - if housing prices increase significantly in a region, people may not be able to buy a house, but they still need housing; that's where the renter's market comes in to play - someone buys a housing unit because they *can* afford it, and then rents it out to other people who *can't* afford the housing unit.
3. The person who is selling something than most people who used to be able to afford the demand may have a way to stockpile the thing until others who *can* afford the increased price can pay for the additional cost of the supply. Thinking of housing units again - if you own one and you rent it out, ideally you might want to not let it go a month without renting it out, but if you hold to a specific rent price, you might be better off to wait a month, even if nobody is going to occupy the empty home.

Hopefully this showcases the problem a bit clearly in that context; that is, raising gas prices to try reduce demand from using gasoline would be sort of similar to a plan to reduce demand for housing units by raising the price of housing units. There's still a demand for the thing people want, but fewer people will be able to afford it - and the people who *can* afford it may be able to ignore the increase in cost and buy it anyways.

Which is why, despite trying to get carbon-conscious energy sources up and running to replace carbon emission linked energy sources, until that's a viable replacement for the amount of energy that is in demand, lower prices for the existing energy sources ensures that a larger segment of people who constitute the demand for energy sources can in fact actually afford the energy sources available to their means (I.e. not everyone can afford an electric car and ensure it gets powered by non carbon emitting sources - until they can, they're *stuck* with the existing systems available.).

Comment: The true “needs” of a person are very small - people in the 19th century did just fine with a lot less. So yes, there is baseline level of “need” but it’s much lower than claimed by activists and politicians.

Comment: The analogy for the 19th Century sort of falls apart when you remember that [milk delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_delivery) was a thing back then - at that time, people replaced refrigeration tied energy towards horse drawn vehicle energy consumption, a bit of exporting their energy footprint. Since then, however, we've had significant differences in how we get milk to people via grocery stores, and deliver to those stores directly instead - across longer distances, because our vehicles can go farther and export energy footprint for delivery across more people.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there could be a pragmatic reason for wanting to cap energy prices: high energy prices cause deaths.

[Source](https://www.economist.com/interactive/graphic-detail/2022/11/26/high-fuel-prices-could-kill-more-europeans-than-fighting-in-ukraine-has)

> The only firm conclusion our model provides is that if the patterns from 2000-19 do continue to apply in 2022-23, Russia’s energy weapon will prove highly potent. With electricity prices near their current levels, around 147,000 more people (4.8% more than average) would die in a typical winter than if those costs returned to the average from 2015-19. Given mild temperatures—using the warmest winter during the past 20 years for each country—this figure would fall to 79,000, a 2.7% increase. And with frigid ones, using each country’s coldest winter since 2000, it would climb to 185,000, a rise of 6.0%.
>
> The size of this effect varies by country. Italy has the most predicted deaths, owing to its soaring electricity costs and big, ageing population. The model does not account for Italy’s generous new subsidies for households, which focus on poorer users. These transfers would need to be very effective to offset such high prices. Estonia and Finland also do poorly on a per-person basis. At the opposite extreme, France and Britain, which have imposed price ceilings, fare reasonably well, and predicted mortality in Spain is nearly flat. In Austria, which will cap electricity prices up to a modest usage limit at a bargain €0.10 per kilowatt-hour, deaths are expected to fall.

However, the article doesn't mention climate change, which is presumably also going to kill quite a few people, but "sometime in the future".

Comment: The quoted answer is bad because the climate change people project tens of millions of climate change deaths in the future. So in theory losing 1 million people to save tens of millions later should seem like a good deal.

Answer (score -4):

**Because it remains to be seen if green solutions are actually green.**

I have seen articles stating the problem (see links below) but have yet to see a refutation: green energy isn't very green. Convincing people to pay more for electricity, which is primarily a result of switching to more expensive "green" solutions such as wind and solar, when the generation sources are of dubious actual improvement to the environment is going to be a hard sell.

e.g., anchoring a wind turbine takes a lot of concrete, so you need loads of concrete to be mixed and installed (which is going to be done with diesel trucks). Wind and solar require a massive footprint compared to any other energy source so unless you can place them in desert or tundra, you could be looking at chopping down forests in order to place energy collection grids. Since they are thus distributed, you need loads of copper wiring to connect them all, creating a complex grid with many additional points of failure/maintenance. Snow and ice have to be handled (generally via self-heating, which further reduces the net energy output). The ups and downs of wind and solar also require solutions for energy storage, which typically means lithium batteries on a large scale.

And then there's the replacement schedule. Solar panels begin degrading in terms of efficiency the day they are installed, with the 20-25 year mark typically being the point where they are replaced. Wind similarly has about a 20 year life span as a standard replacement point. Replacing them is another energy intensive operation (and, again, must cover a very wide area as the whole energy grid is dispersed). Add further costs (both in money and energy expended) to anything that was installed off-shore.

In the end, you are expending an incredible amount of money, resources, and energy to create a solution that has a short life span and must be regularly replaced, almost in its entirety, and additionally requires a huge amount of land (which also faces a "NIMBY" effect. Not In My Backyard. Everyone wants wind power, but few people want it installed on the hills around their house.)

If you want people to pay more to save the environment, they need some better assurances that the environment is not actually just going to be destroyed even faster by the so-called solution.

Supporting evidence:

"Wind Turbine Blade Waste in 2050" (University of Cambridge, 2017)
https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/263878/Liu_and_Barlow-2017-Waste_Management-AM.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

"Wind turbines generate mountains of waste" https://www.cfact.org/2020/09/28/wind-turbines-generate-mountains-of-waste/

"Solar panels generate mountains of waste" https://townhall.com/columnists/dugganflanakin/2020/09/17/solar-panels-generate-mountains-of-waste-n2576390

"Delving more deeply, generating 20% of US electricity with wind power would require up to 185,000 1.5-MW turbines, 19,000 miles of new transmission lines, 18 million acres, and 245 million tons of concrete, steel, copper, fiberglass and rare earths – plus fossil-fuel backup generators for the 75-80% of the year that winds nationwide are barely blowing and the turbines are not producing electricity." https://climatechangedispatch.com/monumental-unsustainable-environmental-impacts/

"Concrete: the world's third largest CO2 emitter" https://www.rte.ie/news/world/2021/1029/1256726-concrete-co2-emitter/

Comment: *Convincing people to pay more for electricity* The idea in the OP Is to get people to use less, though.

Comment: Is this *actually* the answer to the question, or just a reason why a small minoritry of people oppose regenerative energy?

Comment: @Philipp This being the Politics exchange, it's the political answer: it's why I oppose it and I see no reason to think it's a "small minority of people" who agree with me. If you want to raise people's cost of living, you must justify it, and the solar/wind movement has failed to do so, which is why OP is noticing the problem. If this was Skeptics, I would dig up more proof, but as a political answer I believe it's sufficient. Public sentiment and all.

Comment: @JamieB I think you misunderstand the purpose of this community. This is not an opinion exchange. Here we answer objective questions on politics and poltical processes without indulging in our personal opinions on the subject matter. For more information, check the help center article ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Philipp Every answer in here is an opinion. The question was why people don't welcome paying more. The answer (one of many) is because the cost has not been justified or proven to be the solution to the problem (it might make the problem worse). Disagreeing with a political opinion does not mean it doesn't fit the community.

Comment: @Allure I see it as all connected, though: higher prices aren't arbitrary. They are driven by either changes in fossil fuel availability or by switching to "climate friendly" energy sources. I think people *would* welcome higher prices with open arms, as the OP states, if it was justified. It is not justified, is the point I am making. It might even be justified against mass implementation of wind and solar (we are paying more AND damaging the environment while we do it. I added links to show where this is coming from.)

Comment: Notice that the stupid theories like "wind turbines bad because garbage" only came up once Russia really wanted to sell a whole lot more oil.

Comment: @user253751 Not true -- those were just the top articles I got from a quick google search. If you look at the "References" section of this paper you can find all kinds of articles dating back over a decade about this topic: https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/263878/Liu_and_Barlow-2017-Waste_Management-AM.pdf?sequence=1&amp;isAllowed=y

Comment: @JamieB was anyone using it as a serious reason to object to replacing fossil fuels (which produce far more waste) with wind turbines?

Comment: @user253751 Do they? Citation needed. I'm citing my sources. Let's see yours.

Comment: You are forgetting as we move to more green power sources including vehicles we will no longer have issues such as diesel pollution from construction equipment. Trying to ignore that fact isn't being very honest. Sure it is an issue now but it will not be an issue as we progress.

Comment: @JoeW Replacing construction equipment remains to be seen. They are enormous power hogs and current grid usage does not account for them. I'm not entirely sure you even CAN put a construction crane on the grid. How much electricity would that use? Can the local wires even handle that much? What size lithium battery runs a construction crane for 4 hours? afaik, these do not exist even as concepts today.

Comment: With the goal of replacing all vehicles with electric there is no way they won't do that with construction equipment as well as you can get much more power out of an electric motor then you can a gas/diesel engine.

Comment: @JoeW Power output definitely isn't the problem. It's power input. Same reason you can't run a bunch of 1500W space heaters in your office. You could trip a circuit breaker. You could burn the building down by melting wires. There are limits to what the local grid can handle, too, not to mention the overall grid. There is no technical limitation, but don't underestimate the amount of retooling required to enable you to *plug in* construction equipment. Quick google... 900 hp bulldozer = 671 kW. At 250kW/acre, you need 2.7 acres of solar panels per bulldozer.)

Comment: You are correct there are limits today but that doesn't mean those limits won't change as technology improves.

Comment: @JamieB Consider that many large factories already use large amounts of electric power (as well as non-electric power). *Trains* use electric power. Is a crane much worse than a subway car? Another point: that bulldozer doesn't run at maximum power all the time - in fact, an electric one can save energy because it doesn't need to idle. If you just listen to a construction site you can realize a lot of the equipment in use idles at quite a high speed so the hydraulic power is available at the few moments it's needed.